# What do I do after pygame.init() produces output (6,0) in IDLE?

Tags: macos, terminal, pygame, python-idle

I have just installed pygame on mac, and my python is 2.7,

After i did import pygame, and pygame.init() - it just typed out 6,0 and opened some empty icon.

[image: ffff]
What do I do now?

How can I connect IDE to open after i do pygame.init() in terminal?

Comment: Read the pygame.init doc for what the return value means.  Perhaps it is the pygame version.  Consider acting on the warning.  I don't understand 'connect IDE to open'.  This question does not seem connected to IDLE, but I will note that while tkinter and pygame cannot both run in the same process (as they would compete to control the screen), one can run pygame programs from IDLE's tkinter-based editor when it is in the default mode of running user code in a separate process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by reading the documentation.

pygame.init() isn't an installation command.  It is a command that should be in your game module to load the pygame components you need.

Once you have initialized the pygame modules, you need to do the following:
- Set up the display (size, background color, etc)
- Set up your Sprites (enemies, players, platforms, etc)
- Set up your update routine (what happens every time the screen gets refreshed?  This needs to include player/enemy movement, collision detection, other game logic)
- Set up your physics engine (for lack of a better term).  Does gravity pull your player and enemies down when they are falling?  If so how.
- User input - set up keyboard and joystick commands.
- Music and Sound effects?

Or are you just looking to play other peopel's PyGame games?  If that is the case, read the specifics of their documentation.  Some of them cane be run with just "python .py"